# Php OOP use my function in other class without extends

Tags: php, oop

I'm a begginer in OOP, i have an `Database` Class which have no children, a `userInfo` class which is the mother and a `login` class which is the daughter.

In the `Database Manager`, i have this `function`

```
public function usernameExist(userInfo $user)
    {

        $q = $this->_db->prepare('SELECT COUNT(username) FROM register where username=:username');
        // on bind
        $q->bindValue(':username', $user->username());
        $q->execute();
        $donnees = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        // on verifie le contenu de $donnees
        if($donnees['COUNT(username)'] >= '1')
        {
            // l'utilisateur existe on retourne true
            return true;
        }



    }
```

**my Database Manager**
I could make a Dynamic function for everything but i think it's easier to read like that, but whatever i'm a noob =).

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: Arnaud
 * Date: 29/11/2016
 * Time: 23:52
 */
class Manager
{
    protected $_db;

    public function __construct($db)
    {
        $this->setDB($db);
    }

    //getter
    // on regarde si le nom d'utilisateur est déjà pris
    public function usernameExist(userInfo $user)
    {

        $q = $this->_db->prepare('SELECT COUNT(username) FROM register where username=:username');
        // on bind
        $q->bindValue(':username', $user->username());
        $q->execute();
        $donnees = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        // on verifie le contenu de $donnees
        if($donnees['COUNT(username)'] >= '1')
        {
            // l'utilisateur existe on retourne true
            return true;
        }



    }

    // methode pour verifier si l'email entrée existe
    public function emailExist(userInfo $user)
    {
        try
        {
            $q = $this->_db->prepare('SELECT COUNT(email) FROM register WHERE email=:email');
            $q->bindValue(':email', $user->email());
            $q->execute();
        }
        catch (PDOException $e)
        {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
        // on réccupère les infos
        $donnees = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        //si l'email existe on renvois true
        if($donnees['COUNT(email)'] >= '1')
        {
            return true;
        }
        // sinon false
        elseif($donnees['COUNT(email)'] == '0')
        {
            return false;
        }





    }

    //ajout de l'utilisateur

    public function ajout(userInfo $user)
    {
        $q = $this->_db->prepare('INSERT INTO register(username,password,email) VALUES(:username,:password,:email)');

        $q->bindValue(':username', $user->username());
        $q->bindValue(':password', $user->password());
        $q->bindValue(':email', $user->email());

        $q->execute();

        // si tout s'est bien passé
        $donnees = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


    }

    //suppression d'un  utilisateur
    public function suppression(userInfo $user)
    {
      $q = $this->_db->query('DELETE FROM register WHERE username='.$user->username());

      if($q)
      {
          return true;
      }
    }

    // reccuppéré l'id selon l'username ou email
    public function getID(userInfo $user,$methode)
    {
        // si la méthode demandée est de retrouver l'id selon le nom utilisateur
        if($methode == 'username')
        {
            $q = $this->_db->prepare('SELECT id FROM register WHERE username=:username');
            $q->bindValue(':username', $user->username());
            $q->execute();
            $donnees = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            return $donnees['id'];
        }
        // si il est demandé par email
        if($methode == 'email')
        {
            $q = $this->_db->prepare('SELECT id FROM register WHERE email=:email');
            $q->bindValue(':email', $user->email());
            $q->execute();
            $donnees = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            return $donnees['id'];
        }


    }

    public function passwordMatch(login $user,$password)
    {
        $q = $this->_db->prepare('SELECT password FROM register WHERE username=:username');
        $q->bindValue(':username', $user->username());
        $q->execute();
        $donnees = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        if($donnees['password'] == $password)
        {
            return true;
        }
        elseif($donnees['password'] != $password)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    //setter
    public function setDB(PDO $db)
    {
        $this->_db = $db;
    }
}
```

my login class which is nearly empty because i'm stuck.

**Login Class**

```
class login extends userInfo
{

    protected $_dbParam;



   public function usernameExistParam(Manager $db)
   {
       // well i'm stuck x)
   }



}

?>
```

My `login` class extends from `userInfo`(mother), how can i call the `usernameExists` function using the login(children) class ? because the (userInfo...) parameters is blocking me

thanks !

Comment: You need to call `usernameExists` function inside `Login` class?

Comment: If you want to call `usernameExists` function inside `Login` class, you need to pass `Database` object into the function inside `Login`.

Comment: Small note: Change `SELECT COUNT(username)` to `SELECT COUNT(username) as cnt` and then you can use `$donnees['cnt']` instead of `$donnees['COUNT(username)']`

Comment: By the way, also post `Login` class in the question. So, it would be more clear.

Comment: Read about `Dependency injection`. Add a method (`setDB($database)`) & a property (`protected $db`) to the `Login` (or mother-class) then you can call `usernameExist` within the `Login` class via `$this->db->usernameExist($this)`.

Comment: Last Note: `usernameExist` should be in `userInfo` not in the general `Database` class. Like `public function usernameExist(Database $db)` in `userInfo`. But i dont know your class-structure, so, just an hint...

Comment: Why Login inherits from UserInfo, Login could be intended as an authenticated user, but it's mostly like a state than a specialization

Answer (score -1):

if your function can be used without context (which seems to be the case here), just define it as a static method so you can call it from anywhere like this : `Database::usernameExists()`

Otherwise, you must pass the `Database` object to the `Login` class